# Determine if the following Markov chain is positive recurrent, null recurrent or transcient.

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-theory, markov-chains, markov-process

We consider the Markov Chain with transition probabilities 
$$
p(i,0)=\frac{1}{i^2 +2},\qquad p(i,i+1)= \frac{i^2 +1}{i^2 +2}.
$$

Determine if this Markov chain is positive recurrent, null recurrent  or transcient.

[image]

**My attempt:** Since all states are connected to $0$, then it is sufficient to determine if $0$ is a positive recurring state.
Consider $T_{0}$ the hitting time, that is
$$T_{0}=\inf\left\{m\geq 1\: :\: X_{m}=0\right\}.$$
Note that 
$$
\mathbb{P}(T_{0}=n|X_{0}=0)=\left(\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{2}{3}\times\cdots\times\frac{(n-2)^2+1}{(n-2)^{2}+2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)^{2}+2}\right)
$$
Therefore, we have
$$
\mathbb{E}(T_{0}|X_{0}=0)=\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\times \left(\frac{1}{2}\times\frac{2}{3}\times\cdots\times\frac{(n-2)^2+1}{(n-2)^{2}+2}\right)\left(\frac{1}{(n-1)^{2}+2}\right).
$$
I need to determine if this series converges or diverges. I have tried to limit it superiorly and inferiorly but I have not found good bounds.

Comment: My intuition is that this chain is transient because $p(i,i+1)$ is increasing with $i$ and $p(i,0)$ is decreasing with $i$. But I will have to take a closer look at the problem tomorrow.

Comment: @Math1000 I think you're right, though the essential fact is maybe not just that $p(i, 0)$ is *decreasing*, but that it is in fact *summable*. I'm working on a complete answer right now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The chain is actually **transient**.

First, let me address your question about the sum: because of the transience of the chain, if you correctly compute $\mathbb E[T_0 \mid X_0 = 0]$ you would apparently get $\infty$. This will be a disappointing result, of course, because it won't settle the original question; you will only know that the chain is not positive recurrent, but it could still be either null recurrent or transient.

Proof of transience: There is precisely one path that starts at $0$, leaves, and does not return; it's the path for which all steps are to the right. The probability of this path is equal to 
$$\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^2 + 1}{i^2 + 2},$$
whence recurrence is equivalent to that product being $0$. We'll check by turning the product into a sum via a logarithm:
$$\log \left(\prod_{i=0}^{\infty}\frac{i^2 + 1}{i^2 + 2} \right) = \sum_{i=0}^{\infty} \log \left(\frac{i^2 + 1}{i^2 + 2} \right) \tag{$\bigstar$}$$
I claim the sum converges to a negative number instead of diverging to $-\infty$, as follows. If we negate the terms we have
$$\log \left( \frac{i^2 + 2}{i^2 + 1} \right) = \log \left(1 + \frac{1}{i^2 + 1} \right).$$
Note that for $x > 0$, we have $\log(1 + x) < x$; hence, we have
$$\log \left( \frac{i^2 + 2}{i^2 + 1} \right) < \frac{1}{i^2 + 1}$$
and since the right side is summable, so also is the left.

This implies that the sum in ($\bigstar$) converges to a finite negative number (instead of diverging to $-\infty$), so the the infinite product above it is therefore positive, and the chain is transient.

---

Here's another way to see the transience of the chain. I'm not sure if it's cleaner either conceptually or computationally; I'll leave that decision to the reader.

Consider a chain started at state $n \neq 0$, and for let $A_k$ denote the event that the walk takes exactly $k$ steps to the right (from state $n$) before then taking one step back to $0$. Clearly $\mathbb P(A_0) = \frac{1}{n^2 + 2}$, and you can verify that for $k \geq 1$,
$$\mathbb P(A_k) = \left[\prod_{i=0}^{k-1} \frac{(n+i)^2+1}{(n+i)^2 + 2}\right] \frac{1}{(n+k)^2+2} \leq \frac{1}{(n+k)^2 + 2}.$$
 Note that $\{T_0 < \infty\}$ can be expressed as a *disjoint* union $ \cup_{k=0}^{\infty} A_k$, so
$$\mathbb P(T_0 < \infty \mid X_0 = n) = \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \mathbb P (A_k) \leq \sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(n+k)^2 + 2} = \sum_{k=n}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2 + 2}. \tag{$\bigstar \bigstar$}$$
Since the full series
$$\sum_{k=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{k^2 + 2}$$
converges, this implies that the rightmost side of ($\bigstar \bigstar$) can be made arbitrarily small; in particular, it can be made less than $1$. This implies that there is some $n$ for which a chain started there has a probability less than $1$ of ever returning to $0$, which proves the transience of the chain (since it is irreducible).

Comment: Great answer. I was busy today and did not have time to get around to looking at this problem. But I don't think I would have produced such a fine result.